# How to set gradient background color in react-native Navbar?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

How to achieve this sorta color on nav bar with react-native-router-flux.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check a custom `navbar` example in the link
https://github.com/infinitered/ignite-ir-boilerplate-2016/blob/master/boilerplate/App/Navigation/CustomNavBar.js

Use [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient) to create gradient in a component and use it as a custom navbar see following line

```
<Scene key='sceneKey' component={Component} title='Component' navBar={CustomNavBar} />
```

Answer (score 0):

with an image or [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient) create a greadient and place it under navbar and make the navber transparent or you can create your custom `navBar` component using something similar to [react-native-router-flux-nav-bar](https://github.com/sprmn/react-native-router-flux-nav-bar)

Comment: i'm using react-native-router-flux for navigation. Any Example for this?

Comment: you can check this [react-native-router-flux-nav-bar](https://github.com/sprmn/react-native-router-flux-nav-bar)

Comment: you will need to make something like that & place the gradient as background